# Why doesn't assert do anything? What do I need to do to get it to work?

Tags: c, cuda

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    assert(1 == 0);
    assert(false);

    cout << "we got here" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

with the above code, `we got here` is outputted to the console window.

Also, I notice that assert is defined as:

```
#define assert(expression) ((void)0)
```

Not very fluent in C/C++ any more and CUDA C is about the same.

Comment: You probably defined the macro `NDEBUG` somewhere (eg. during the build for example, typically if you build a project in release with many build systems)

Comment: @JérômeRichard You got it! An example I did had me set up the Release build configuration. Changing to Debug configuration and I got an abort(). Make an answer, Ill mark it as correct.